# Address of variable supplied instead of its value

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I wan testing an example of `fopen` and `fclose` in C++ where the code reads the integer values in thee file but if the file is empty (no integers), the value retrieved is not 0 but `-858993460`. i think this is the address of the variable in `fscanf()` but how could i get the `null` or `/0` value
the following code is problematic

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    {
        int a, sum = 0 ,num, n = 0;
        FILE* pFile;
        pFile = fopen("input.txt", "r");
        fscanf(pFile, "%d", &num);
        while (n != 5) {
            n = n + 1;
            sum = sum + num;
            fscanf(pFile, "%d", &num);
            
        }
        fclose(pFile);
        printf("I have read: %d numbers and sum is %d \n", n, sum);
        scanf("Hi %d", &a);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

input.txt : (empty) or :

`12 32 43 56 78`

NOTE: the code is problematic because `num` is never read as `0` so the loop keeps going on.

I will add further details on the problem: if the input file contains five integers:

`12 32 43 56 78`

and the code goes as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    {
        char str[80];
        int a, sum = 0 ,num, n = 0;
        FILE* pFile;
        pFile = fopen("input.txt", "r");
        fscanf(pFile, "%d", &num);
        while (n != 5) {
            n = n + 1;
            sum = sum + num;
            fscanf(pFile, "%d", &num);
            
        }
        fclose(pFile);
        printf("I have read: %d numbers and sum is %d \n", n, sum);
        scanf("Hi %d", &a);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

output:

`I have read: 5 numbers and sum is 221`

Comment: Don't tag `C` if you are using `C++`.

Comment: `-858993460` = `0xFFFF FFFF CCCC CCCC`, I'm guessing this is not an address.

Comment: There's no way to tell what might be wrong with your code if you don't show it to us.

Comment: Add your code to your question and we might be able to help.

Comment: You never check that `fopen` succeeds. You never check that `fscanf` succeeds. Always check the return values from functions that may fail.

Comment: Also, you've swapped the arguments here: `printf("I have read: %d numbers and sum is %d \n", sum, num);` - it should be `printf("I have read: %d numbers and sum is %d \n", num, sum);`

Comment: The shown code is very schizophrenic. It `#include`s a C++ header file, then proceeds to use absolutely nothing from it, but from C's `stdio.h`, which is not even included.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, i know but i didnt care about order because it already wasn't giving any output

Comment: @mohamed Ok, but you also do not check that `fopen` and `fscanf` succeeds. That's more important.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, that's why i didn't put the code first time i wrote the question i had to cut part of the whole project to show the faulty point which didnt show the include `stdio.h` and instead showed the part where i used `io.stream` becuase i used stdin and `stdout` later

Comment: @TedLyngmo, i already know the problem is with reading the value becuase i tried several times changing and tweaking the code (the reading process is correct the problem is with the value), i checked that using breakpoints

Comment: The problem with the shown code is that it fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, i fixed the code now it should be reproducible .(the debugger is not going to ahow any input because it is stuck in the while statement)

Comment: How do you expect the shown code to be "reproducible" when it doesn't show the input file being read?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, thats the function of `fscanf` it reads the file for integer values then stores them at the address of `num`

Comment: Do you understand that in order to reproduce your problem, it is necessary to show what's in `input.txt`? Can you explain how you expect anyone to compile and run the program,and reproduce your problem,without `input.txt`?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, understood and modified the question\

Comment: Ok, so, there are five integers, their sum is 221, and that's what the program shows. I see no problems.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, yes it works because i already know how many integers are in the file but when i try to make the code global to work on any file without the need to predefine the numbers of iteration it fails because it can't read the end of the file (when num is supposed to be zero it gives the weird number(-858993460))

Comment: *if the file is empty (no integers), the value retrieved is not 0* You never initialize `num`, it keeps an undetermined initial value if the file is empty. *num is supposed to be zero* Where have you got it from? Read the fscanf manual carefully.

Comment: @273K, i got the code from book (learn to program with C by Noel Kalicharan), i know that this is intended for a C project but i checked that these function work the same in both languages. However, when i initialized num = 0 the code worked. i have read fscanf manual but didn't recognize this aspect of the function. I would like to know which manual did you refere to? and what could the strange number be?

Comment: *Return value
1-3) Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned (which may be zero in case a matching failure occurred before the first receiving argument was assigned), or EOF if input failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned.* Your fscanf returns 0 or EOF, that means 0 receiving arguments were assigned. The strange number is unspecified any number in an uninitialized variable, and getting what it could be is waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is simple, never miss returned values of IO functions.

```
FILE* pFile;
// pFile = fopen("input.txt", "r");
// fscanf(pFile, "%d", &num);
// while (n != 5) {
if ((pFile = fopen("input.txt", "r")) == NULL)  // If unable to open file
    return 1;
while (n != 5 && fscanf(pFile, "%d", &num) == 1) {  // And if num is successfully assigned
    n = n + 1;
    sum = sum + num;
    // Odd: fscanf(pFile, "%d", &num);
}
fclose(pFile);
```

Answer (score 2):

A more C++ way of doing this would be as shown below. You can use this as a reference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
    std::ifstream inputFile("input.txt");
    
    std::string line;
    int num = 0, sum = 0; //always initialize built in types in local/block scope 
    
    if(inputFile)
    {
        //go line by line
        while(std::getline(inputFile, line))
        {
            std::istringstream ss(line);
            
            //go through individual numbers
            while(ss >> num)
            {
                sum += num;
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    else 
    {
        std::cout<<"Input file cannot be read"<<std::endl;
    }
    inputFile.close();
    
    std::cout << "The sum of all the intergers from the file is: "<<sum<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/2sY8InSe9).

Comment: @i use std:: often but i wanted to try fopen and fscanf also.

Comment: @mohamed Ok you can use whichever method you find more suitable for your needs. I showed one way of doing it.

Comment: @mohamed This way is also among the most common ways of doing it in C++.